# Unknown Javascript expression

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me what this javascript code does? I came across it in a jQuery routine to select table rows.

Each of the following can range from -1 to the table-row count -1:

- lastIndex is the row number of the last-seleted row.
- thisIndex is the row number of the currently-selected row.

Code:

```
thisIndex = [lastIndex, lastIndex = thisIndex][0] ;
```

Help!

Comment: please add your html and js code.

Comment: It's a "tricky" way of interchanging the values of `thisindex` and `lastindex`.

Comment: You'd think you could just do `[thisIndex, lastIndex] = [lastIndex, thisIndex]` now that destructuring is a thing.

Comment: Other (clearer) ways to [swap variables](https://dmitripavlutin.com/swap-variables-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

This is one method to swap the two values inside the variables `thisIndex` and `lastIndex` without using a temporary variable.

On the RHS, there is an array of two values and [0] will return the first value.

example: Suppose

```js
thisIndex  = 10;
lastIndex = 20;

[lastIndex, lastIndex = thisIndex]
```

will become

```
[20,10]
```

and then assign 20 to `lastIndex`, the expression returns 10 which is assigned to `thisIndex`